# Is this proof for pumping lemma legit?

Tags: automata, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

Prove that $L=\{a^{n}b^{m}c^{k}\mid n\leq(m+k)\}$ is not regular.

I used the pumping lemma as follow:

there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$

$z=uvw$

$|uv|\leq n  , |v|\geq1$

$uv^iw$ is a string in L, so I need to find i such that $uv^iw$ $\notin L$

I rewritten L so that condition will appear as follow: $n-m\leq k$

I set $i$ to be $k+1$ placing it in $uv^iw$ I get $uv^{k+1}w$==> $a^nb^{k+1-n}c^k$ and we can see that the inequality is incorrect: $n+k+1-n\leq k$
simplfying the expression: $1\leq 0$ which is false.

is this way of proving non regular language is correct?

Comment: It doesn’t make any sense to me, starting with the confusing use of n for two different things. _You_ can pick w=xyz, so pick it.

Comment: It cannot work for arbitrary uvw because it doesn’t work if n=0.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.